# Wordpress: Osetin Meal Planer, Adding %author% in custom post type URL structure?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to do some WordPress URL rewriting ...

Specifically I have custom post type that currently works like this:

```
mydomain.com/videos/post-title/
```

But I would like to have it located at:

```
mydomain.com/videos/author-name/post-title/
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

NOTE: I'm using OSETIN MEAL PLANER plugin in my site. Using that plugin for publishing recipe/post on website.

Answer (score 0):

using Jhon's Custom Post Permalinks plugin it should be easy using:

/%post_type%/%author%/%postname%/

also you can try this

add_filter( 'your-post-type_post_type_args', '_my_rewrite_slug' ); // Here replace "your-post-type" with the actual post type, e.g., "cherry_services", "cherry-projects"
function _my_rewrite_slug( $args ) {
$args['rewrite']['slug'] = '/videos/author-name'; // Replace "our-/videos/author-name" with your preferable slug
return $args;
}